# MongoDB MapReduce issue in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce, deserialization

I'm working on a relative trival **MongoDB MapReduce** demo in **C#**.

The code is as follows:

```
    public List<CategorySummaryResult> GetCategorySummaries()
    {
        string map = @"
            function() {
                var key = this.FeedType;
                var value =  {count: 1, names: this.Name};
                emit(key, value);
            }";

        string reduce = @"
            function(key, values) {
                var result =  {count: 0, names: ''};

                values.forEach(function(value) {
                    result.count += value.count;
                    result.names += ',' + value.names;
                });

                return result;
            }";

        string finalize = @"
            function(key, value) {
                if (value.names.charAt(0) === ',')
                    value.names = value.names.substr(1);

                return value;                  
            }";

        var options = 
            MapReduceOptions
                .SetFinalize(finalize)
                .SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);

        var result =
            _db.GetCollection("NewsCategories")
                .MapReduce(map, reduce, options)
                .GetInlineResultsAs<CategorySummaryResult>()
                .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

Objects to deserialize to:

```
public class CategorySummaryResult
{
    public double id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategorySummary> value { get; set; }
}

public class CategorySummary
{
    public double count { get; set; }
    public string names { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how the BSON output looks like:

```
[0]: { "_id" : 1.0, "value" : { "count" : 3.0, "names" : "Games,Technologie,Auto" } }
[1]: { "_id" : 2.0, "value" : { "count" : 1.0, "names" : "Hoofdpunten" } }
```

However I keep getting the following exception:

```
An error occurred while deserializing the value property of class MetroNews.Managers.CategorySummaryResult:
 Expected element name to be '_t', not 'count'.
```

What's going wrong and **how can I fix it**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot properly serialize/deserialize an ICollection.

It will serialize fine into a list of whatever objects but the problem occurs when you want to deserialize it.

The deserializer cannot instantiate an ICollection and does not know what specific type of to use without you specifying it through conventions.

you should change

```
public class CategorySummaryResult
{
   public double id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<CategorySummary> value { get; set; }
}
```

to something like

```
public class CategorySummaryResult
{
   public double id { get; set; }
   public List<CategorySummary> value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and your're sure your mongodb is not "poluted" with old data?

Comment: The non-deserialized data, as posted above, looks fine.
The error lies with the deserialization.

Comment: the JSON data you posted above is not valid for a list of CategorySummary and will not deserialize into a list. it will deserialize into an object with the properties "count" and "names".

Comment: you're right! how did I miss that?
'value' should be of type CategorySummary, not a list of it.
thank you!
in my defence, that is one misleading error message :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[BsonDiscriminatorAttribute(required=true)]` to your `CategorySummary` class.